# Save/Cancel dialog buttons not showing in Magnolia dialog

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I am trying to add a dialog to my app, and while I have no issues defining the form I want the way I want, the Save and Cancel buttons simply aren't showing up and I don't know why.  I'm new to Magnolia and custom apps, so sure I'm missing something, but I've gone through the sections in the documentation I can find, but from everything I've seen, this should work.

```
    detailFeatured:
        subAppClass: info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.DetailSubApp
        class: info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.DetailSubAppDescriptor
        actions:
            commit:
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.action.SaveFormActionDefinition
                label: "Save"
            cancel:
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.action.CancelFormActionDefinition
                label: "Cancel"
        editor:
            wide: true
            actions:
                - name: commit
                - name: cancel
            form:
                tabs:
                    - name: featured
                        label: "Featured Slideshows"
                        fields:

                            - name: ogLabel
                                label: ""
                                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.StaticFieldDefinition
                                value: "<strong>Hero Slideshow</strong>"

                            - name: hero
                                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
                                required: true
                                label: Slideshow URI

                            - name: ogLabel
                                label: ""
                                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.StaticFieldDefinition
                                value: ""
                            - name: ogLabel
                                label: ""
                                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.StaticFieldDefinition
                                value: "<strong>Slideshow Carousel</strong>"


                            - name: carousel
                                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.MultiValueFieldDefinition
                                required: true
                                label: Slideshow URIs
                                field:
                                        class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
                                        label: URI
            nodeType:
                icon: icon-files
                name: mgnl:featured
        contentConnector:
            workspace: featured
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks alright. Few things to do when you run across something like that:
- Check in the file that you don't have some special invisible chars in the definition instead of just spaces.
- Also make sure you have `magnolia.develop=true` and observe messages in the log when saving definition file. Hopefully that will tell you something useful.
- and last, best of all, go and install Magnolia 5.5 (beta available at time of writing, final should be out as of Nov 15th 2016) and once installed, look at the app via new Definitions App. It should show you all the errors it found in your definition.